# How can I interpret the slice category of a Monoid under its uneque element?

Tags: category-theory

Let $M$ be a monoid, regarded as a category with one single object, $\bullet$. Obviously, the objects of the slice category $\bullet/M$ are all morphisms of $M$, and its morphisms $h:(f: \bullet\rightarrow \bullet) \rightarrow (g:\bullet \rightarrow \bullet)$ are all morphims of $M$ that satisfy $g=hf$. With what can I identify $\bullet/M$ within Abstract Algebra?  For instance, we say that the slice category $c/P$ of a Poset $P$ is the up-set $\uparrow(c)$; I'm trying to do something similar for $M$.

Comment: For the nonnegative real numbers and the positive integers (under addition and multiplication respectively), this is just the usual $\le$ or $\vert$ order, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In general, we can't do better than what you obtained.

The slice category $\bullet/M$ is a category, its objects are the arrows $\bullet\to\bullet$, that is, the elements of $M$, and the arrows $f:a\to b$ are also (labelled by) elements of $M$, namely which satisfy $fa=b$.

If $M$ is right cancelable, $xa=ya\implies x=y$ (e.g. if it is a submonoid of a group), then $\bullet/M$ becomes a posetal category by the order $a\le b$ if $xa=b$ for some (hence a unique) $x$.
As in the comments, it gives the usual ordering in the case $M$ is the additive monoid of nonnegative (integer/real) numbers, and it gives the divisibility relation in the case $M$ is a multiplicative submonoid of an integral domain.